# Is there a way to create persistent random 4 digit numbers in Google Sheets?

Tags: random, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have to create a unique 4-digit numerical ID's through scripts or formulas only in Google Sheets. I am not allowed to copy and paste the values.

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0_i5SJ6Bce2Q/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fdocs%2F_i5SJ6Bce2Q and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587371/script-to-generate-random-numbers-in-multiple-cells should come in handy.

Comment: What purpose do the IDs serve?  Why do you need to generate IDs that are _both_ random _and_ unique?  Can you just use the row and column number instead, which are already unique?

Answer (score 1):

let's say to generate 14x random 4-digit non-repeatable number:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(
 RANDBETWEEN(0, 9*(ROW(1:1000)^0))&
 RANDBETWEEN(0, 9*(ROW(1:1000)^0))&
 RANDBETWEEN(0, 9*(ROW(1:1000)^0))&
 RANDBETWEEN(0, 9*(ROW(1:1000)^0)))), 14, 1)
```

[image: 0]