# Autofill random number google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to add random numbers automatically function

```
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if (col === 2 && row > 1){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(new Rand());
```

if I write instead of `new rand()` - `new Date()` , it's work.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) instead to get a random number between `0` and `1`:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if (col === 2 && row > 1){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(Math.random()); 
}
}
```

If you want to get a random number between `1` and `10` use that inside the `setValue()` method:

```
Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart>1) {
    e.range.setValue(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> if I write instead of new rand() - new Date() , it's work.

`Date()` is a JavaScript Constructor but `Rand()` isn't. To generate a random number you could use `Math.random()`

Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Related

- [Script to generate random numbers in multiple cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20587371/1595451)
- [Generate 'n' unique random number within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41184462/1595451)